# combo box (select) css width issue (any browser)

Tags: html, css, select

There is an inconsistency between the width property typed into the CSS and rendered value in combo boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZceeE/

css:

```
.foo {
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="text" class="foo"><br><br>
<select id="combo" class="foo">
    <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

The "select" element is substracting padding and borders from width before render. Is it normal? If so, theres some documented explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's normal.  That's how the CSS box model works.

http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Comment: Yes. I found an explanation:

Default box-sizing property of text inputs and select inputs are different.

To solve it I just added this property:

    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;

Thanks so much.

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ZceeE/1/